# SQL Server Management Studio - flatten fields list in scripted output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server Management Studio (2005 and up), when I right-click a table and script out a `SELECT` or `INSERT` statement, all columns are listed underneath each other:

```
SELECT 
  [field1]
 ,[field2]
 ,[field3]
 ,[field4]
 ...
FROM dbo.[table1]
```

For tables with a lot of columns this causes me to lose track of the actual T-SQL flow, so I'd prefer the columns on a single line:

```
SELECT [field1], [field2], [fields3], [field4], ...
FROM [table1]
```

Is there any tool (can be an online tool) that takes this output and converts it? Or am I missing an option in the SQL scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Find and Replace.

1. Ctrl+F
2. Quick Replace
3. Check `Use` ->`Regular Expressions`
4. Find Wha`: ",\n\t" (comma, line feed and tabulation)
5. Replace with ", " (comma and space)
6. Replace All

Answer (score 3):

You can visit [sqlformat](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), Change option `List and Parameters Style` to `Not Stacked`

Or

Even you can use `Notepad++` plugin `Poor Man T-SQL formatter` and Changes it options

Comment: sqlformat produces a close result (I still need to remove some excess linebreaks, but it's definately usable).

Answer (score 2):

From Management studio you go to a table or a view, expand it so that you can see the columns folder and then drag the folder onto your query and it will write all the columns of that table in a single row.

Comment: This would be THE answer, if it wasn't that SQL doesn't add the brackets. And I can't change my column names to not include spaces :(.